# Esqueleto where on entity ID

Tags: mysql, yesod, esqueleto

I have been following the examples in Yesod's [SQL Joins](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/sql-joins), and I'd like to add to the Inner Join example also a `where_` clause - it should show only the blogs where author ID is above 1.

I *think* my mistake is probably that I'm doing `E.val 1`, but not sure how to pass it the `Key` it is expecting to get

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    blogs <- runDB
           $ E.select
           $ E.from $ \(blog `E.InnerJoin` author) -> do
                E.on $ blog ^. BlogAuthor E.==. author ^. AuthorId
                E.where_ $ author ^. AuthorId E.>. (E.val 1) -- how to pass ID 1
                E.limit 5
                return
                    ( blog   ^. BlogId
                    , blog   ^. BlogTitle
                    , author ^. AuthorName
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer thanks to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/carymrobbins/d59f9337f5a0c7e00245)

Here's the full example:

```
import Database.Persist.Sql (toSqlKey)
import qualified Database.Esqueleto      as E
import           Database.Esqueleto      ((^.))

getHomeR :: Handler TypedContent
getHomeR = do
    let authorID = toSqlKey 1 :: AuthorId -- cast 1 to the expected key
    let blogsSrc =
             E.selectSource
           $ E.from $ \(blog `E.InnerJoin` author) -> do
                E.on $ blog ^. BlogAuthor E.==. author ^. AuthorId
                E.where_ $ author ^. AuthorId E.>. E.val authorID
                return
                    ( blog   ^. BlogId
                    , blog   ^. BlogTitle
                    , author ^. AuthorName
                    )
```